# Is there a concurrent-access data storage format that can be version controlled?

Tags: database, version-control, version, datastore

I have a project that requires the data storage to be version controlled (e.g. in git or svn). To be clear, I mean versioning of the *contents* of the data store, not the schema. We will take snapshots of the data itself, for example to be able to restore to a previous state. Branch and merge is also needed.

The basic requirements are:

- each data store can reside in its own directory (repository)
- possible to merge divergent versions of the data contents (either manually, or with a tool)
- able to run basic select queries to make a visual report

And ideally:

- safe for concurrent access
- some level of relationship integrity

I've looked at various options. Merge is hard with SQLite (binary format). CouchDB has great merge possibilities (multimaster replication), but doesn't allow different directories for each data store. Plain JSON or other text files make queries and relationships hard.

Is there a data storage format that can be version controlled in this way? How would you solve this problem?

**EDIT (more context):** the specific use case is to implement distributed software issue tracking, in a similar style to [Fossil SCM](http://www.fossil-scm.org). But while I am interested in existing tools that solve this, I'm particularly interested in exploring and understanding different data store options that could be used to build such a tool.

Comment: It's a very interesting Question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic requirements are easy to meet, as @RaydelMiranda already illustrated. For completeness, there exist (mostly young) query language implementations for JSON as well:

- [ObjectPath](http://adriank.github.io/ObjectPath/)
- [JSONSelect](http://jsonselect.org/)
- [JSONiq](http://www.jsoniq.org/)
- [JPath](http://bluelinecity.com/software/jpath)
- [jaql](https://code.google.com/p/jaql/wiki/JaqlOverview)

You could just store your data in JSON, manage the JSON file with a DVCS of your choice and use one of the above languages to query the data. You can also add basic relationship information to any format by just giving records IDs and referring to those IDs from other records.

As far as I know, there is no tool in existence that at the same time also meets either of the "ideally" requirements (Liquibase as mentioned by @LazyBadger looks interesting, but it doesn't version the database itself). However, it is reasonably easy to add safety of concurrent access to the data file by yourself using locks. Note that concurrent use of the *version control* is already safe out of the box, if you use a stock (D)VCS.

Relationship *integrity* is the hardest one to tackle, especially if you stick with the paradigm "create a database file and stick it in a version control system". It would almost certainly require you to do something difficult and hacky, e.g. extending an existing XML/JSON query system to keep the records sorted and to keep an in-memory lookup table to raw file locations (which would be necessary to keep the speed acceptable), or modifying SQLite to use a plain text file format with newlines.

You could also turn the paradigm inside-out: implement version control within an RDBMS like SQLite. That would mostly be a matter of defining a "parent version" relationship and never deleting or updating records, only inserting new versions. To synchronize changes between diverged copies of a database, just exchange all newly inserted records since the last sync and the parent relationship will take care of the rest (modulo some sophistications to prevent primary key conflicts). This is also how stock DVCSs like Git do it. As an added bonus, SQLite and other RDBMSs are already safe to access concurrently.

Comment: Liquibase **can** version data-changes - it's just a question of `Update` changeset vs `Alter`

Comment: Yes, it can version changes to the database, but if you want to version the database itself, that doesn't help.

Comment: "Version database" is 1. Version initial state 2. Version changes

Comment: That is approach #1, aka the changeset approach. Approach #2 is to keep full snapshots and calculate differences on the fly when needed, aka the snapshot approach. The latter is more sensible in most cases, because with the former, comparing two versions or even just reconstructing a version somewhere midway through history quickly becomes very expensive. I think it was also very clear from the original question that MMacdonald needed a snapshot approach.

Answer (score 4):

One solution that comes to my mind is to convert your data into a format that support versioning control. For instance `XML`. Then when you want restore your data to a specific version, just checkout the corresponfing `XML` and do the oposite.

There is also an XML based database engine: [BaseX](http://basex.org/)

Taken from `BaseX` site:

> BaseX is a light-weight, high-performance and scalable XML Database engine and XPath/XQuery 3.0 Processor, which includes full support for the W3C Update and Full Text extensions. An interactive and user-friendly GUI frontend gives you great insight into your XML documents.

You can take a look at this too (Oracle): [Generating XML Data from the Database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb13gen.htm)

Comment: Sounds like BaseX has some similarities to [Berkeley DB XML](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/berkeleydb/overview/index-083851.html)

Comment: In fact `Berkeley DB XML` **support** `BaseX`. Remember `BaseX` is an engine. If you can use `Berkeley DB XML` well problem solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Note**

All up-to-date SCMs have atomic commits, you can just don't worry about it

Follow-up to @RaydelMiranda

- My first idea was also XML (around [Altova XML Tools](http://www.altova.com/xml_tools.html))

From other side you can have SQL backend, but version and exchange only Alter|Update scripts for SQL backend (fullweight solution like [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org) can be considered - I discovered just now, that it can be used with *different* backends: "Supports XML, YAML, JSON and SQL formats" and [Rollback](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/rollback.html) can be used for undoing database-changes)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to lay out the data in a SCM-friendly way, i.e. something like one file per datum (issue, customer report, etc); and run a database on the side whose contents can be reconstructed from the file data at all times.

"Merging" databases such as CouchDB have support for [eventual consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency), as do SCMs; however, they will be slightly different from each other – Typically, databases will go for fully automated merge operations built on top of somewhat byzantine data structures (see for instance the Microsoft paper, [Cloud Types for Eventual Consistency](http://www.msr-waypoint.com/pubs/163842/final-with-color.pdf)), while SCMs will require a (skilled) operator to attend merges and skip the part where they assign meaning to the conflicted lines in the text files to merge.

Eventual consistency is a difficult enough problem in a homogeneous environment (e.g. from CouchDB to CouchDB), you don't want to attempt it cross-system (from CouchDB to say Git, and back).

Given that you want both a database (for ad-hoc queries and referential integrity) and an SCM; and assuming from your question that the user experience you want for merges is closer to the SCM; you might want to set things up so that the SCM is the authoritative data store. You could get a quick start by using CouchDB and committing to SCM a dump made of one JSON file per document. Later on, if you find that merging raw JSON files is too much of a pain, you could refine the dump format (e.g. JSON but with a lot of comments to isolate diff chunks as well as provide user assistance) and/or improve the tool (e.g. warn the user upon merge operations that break referential integrity like when keeping a bug description that points to a nonexistent customer report etc).

Please come back to add your own feedback to this question when you have a prototype going!

Comment: "Please come back to add your own feedback to this question when you have a prototype going!" -- I second that!